# Error: Export of name 'ngModel' not found

Tags: angular, ngmodel

After building my angular project i get the error:
 Error: Export of name 'ngModel' not found!

I have my UI running in a docker container

not even sure where to look for this. Its working fine in dev. (ng serve)

Any ideas

Comment: You have to be more precise in your post. Could you share some code perhaps?

Comment: Doesn't it say what file causes that?

Answer (score 10):

I had the same error (though in dev), it turns out that I had not added the **FormsModule** module to the **app.module.ts** file. See below:

[image]

It is also stated here along with a few more [problems and their corresponding solutions](https://malcoded.com/posts/why-angular-not-works/)

Answer (score 9):

import FormsModule in your respective spec.ts file and app.module.ts if not

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports:[RouterTestingModule,HttpClientTestingModule,FormsModule],
      declarations: [ MyComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to import **FormsModule** in your **.spec.ts** and **app.module.ts** (if necessary) file, as per below:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';    <------ Add this code

describe('Testing Component', () => {
  ...
  ...

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ 
            FormsModule      <------ Add this code
        ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  ...
  ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Another possible issue: if you're using [template form validation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation)
When you set `#name="ngModel"` on a form field without `[(ngModel)]` directive

E.g.

```
<input required [value]="hero.name" (change)="setHeroName($event)" #name="ngModel" >

<div *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)"
  class="alert alert-danger">Error</div>
```

**=> Error: Export of name 'ngModel' not found**

Fixed by replacing

```
[value]="hero.name" (change)="setHeroName($event)"
```

by

```
[(ngModel)]="hero.name"
```

Comment: That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is pretty old, but i had the same problem and want to help people who maybe have the same issue.

So my mistake was, that i forgot to add the ngModel to the input as attribute like so:

Before:

```html
<input type="text" name="email" required email #emailCtrl="ngModel"></input>
```

After:

```html
<input type="text" ngModel name="email" required email #emailCtrl="ngModel"></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a template variable called ngModel. Not sure what affect this had, but removing seemed to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a form and an element within this form, the element should export a control to the parent using `ngModel`.

```
<form (ngSubmit)= "onSubmit()" #f="ngForm">
     <input type="email" id="email" name="email" #email="ngModel">
```

In the above code the input element is not exporting control to the parent form element. The correct code would be:

```
<form (ngSubmit)= "onSubmit()" #f="ngForm">
     <input type="email" id="email" name="email" #email="ngModel">
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Hey, I've formatted your code a bit, but both snippets look the same to me. Maybe I messed up during formatting? Please [edit] your question to fix as needed.