# Angular Template Driven Approche Pass textbox Value to Componet.ts on textbox Change event

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

While practicing validation using Template Driven Approche, got an error as

> Parameter 'val' implicitly has an 'any' type, but a better type may be inferred from usage.ts(7044)

here I am adding related files please help.

```
<form>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <input ngModel name="firstName" #firstName="ngModel" (change)="log(firstName)"  id=firstName type="text" class="form-control">
</div>   
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="comment">Comments</label>
    <textarea   id=comment type="text" cols="5" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<button class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'contact-form',
  templateUrl: './contact-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-form.component.scss']
})
export class ContactFormComponent {

log(val)
{
  console.log(val);
}
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

[image: in the console]

Comment: What is the type that is inferred in visual studio code if you hover over this parameter?

Comment: @PanagiwthsMpougioukos - (parameter) val: any . when i click Ctrl+ . it has been changed to log(val: any)

Comment: which typescript version do you use?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28826

Comment: @PanagiwthsMpougioukos "version": "4.0.5"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added FormsModule in app.module.ts under imports

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule -- Added Here 
    
  ],
```

will be solved the issue for me

Also found an error in the console as
[Error: Export of name 'ngModel' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57725780/error-export-of-name-ngmodel-not-found)