# Error: NG0301: Export of name 'ngModel' not found

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular2-ngmodel

So I'm trying to add a simple validation message.

App.Module.ts

```js
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({
...
 imports: [ FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, ]
})
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Nickname</label>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
    id="nickname" formControlName="nickname" 
    [(ngModel)]="MyProfileForm.nickname" name="nickname" #nickname="ngModel">

    <div [hidden]="nickname.valid" class="alert alert-danger">Nickname is required.</div>
</div>
```

.ts

```js
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators, FormsModule, NgModel } from "@angular/forms";
export class MyProfileComponent
{
    constructor(private fbdr: FormBuilder) { }
    People = ...;
    MyProfileForm: FormGroup;
    this.MyProfileForm = this.fbdr.group
    (
        {
            nickname: new FormControl(this.People.selfnickname, [Validators.required,  Validators.minLength(4)])
        }
    );
}
```

I've tried all answers of this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57725780/5063031).

Full stack from console:

> core.js:6210 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG0301: Export
> of name 'ngModel' not found!. Find more at
> https://angular.io/errors/NG0301 Error: NG0301: Export of name
> 'ngModel' not found!. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0301
> at cacheMatchingLocalNames (core.js:10393)
> at resolveDirectives (core.js:10224)
> at elementStartFirstCreatePass (core.js:14786)
> at ɵɵelementStart (core.js:14823)
> at MyProfileComponent_Template (template.html:21)
> at executeTemplate (core.js:9614)
> at renderView (core.js:9418)
> at renderComponent (core.js:10698)
> at renderChildComponents (core.js:9283)
> at renderView (core.js:9443)
> at resolvePromise (zone.js:1209)
> at resolvePromise (zone.js:1163)
> at zone.js:1275
> at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:402)
> at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28578)
> at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:401)
> at Zone.runTask (zone.js:174)
> at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:578)
> at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:487)
> at invokeTask (zone.js:1596)

Comment: Are those the only one imports you have in your `app.module.ts`?  just FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule?

Comment: You should remove `[(ngModel)]` from FormControl as it is [deprecated](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel-is-deprecated). And I would recommend you try to create Minimal, Reproducible Example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com) as your attached code is not compilable.

Comment: @YongShun I was looking at this [Angular document, No. 4](https://angular.io/guide/forms#show-and-hide-validation-error-messages)

Comment: @Andres2142 There are a lot of other packages.

Comment: Hi @Jeb50, I think you have to remove formControlName and Reactive Form if you follow the documentation you attached. Alternative, if you want to apply Reactive Form, you need to remove `[(ngModel)]` and ngModel directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Concern

There are some issues in your attached code that make the project unable to compile. Be sure you review and [provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

---

### Solution: Angular Template Driven Form

For Template Driven Form, you need to **remove `formControlName` from `input` element**.

Meanwhile, found out that you **miss out `required` attribute** in the `input` element that leads to the error message unable to be displayed.

And remove all related Reactive Form code if you prefer for Template Driven Form.

> my-profile.component.html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"
 id="nickname" [(ngModel)]="People.selfnickname" name="nickname" #nickname="ngModel"
 required>

<div [hidden]="nickname.valid" class="alert alert-danger">Nickname is required.</div>
```

[Solution: Angular Template Driven Form on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-etkmaw)

---

### Solution: Angular Reactive Form

For the Reactive form, you should remove `[(ngModel)]` from `FormControl` as it is [deprecated](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel-is-deprecated).

> my-profile.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="MyProfileForm">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Nickname</label>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
  id="nickname" formControlName="nickname" 
  name="nickname">

    <div [hidden]="MyProfileForm.controls['nickname']?.valid" class="alert alert-danger">Nickname is required.</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

> my-profile.component.ts

```js
export class MyProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  MyProfileForm!: FormGroup;
  People: { selfnickname: string } = {
    selfnickname: ''
  };

  constructor(private fbdr: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.MyProfileForm = this.fbdr.group({
      nickname: new FormControl(this.People.selfnickname, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(4)
      ])
    });
  }
}
```

[Solution: Angular Reactive Form on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xes4pw)

Would suggest [Angular Reactive Form documentation](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) as a great resource for you can to follow the instructions and guidelines while creating your form.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed info and terrific demos!